# Why is a Django model taking so long to load in admin?

Tags: django

I have a fairly simple Django set up for a forum, and one of the most basic models is this, for each thread:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    last_reply = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True, null=True)
    username = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="forumuser")

    fixed = models.BooleanField(_("Sticky"), default=False)
    closed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    markdown_enabled = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    reply_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    title = models.CharField(_("Title Post"), max_length=255)
    content = models.TextField(_("Content"), blank=False)
    rating = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    followers = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    ip_address = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return "/post/%s/" % self.id
```

Then we have some replies:

```
class PostReply(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='replyuser')
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name='replypost')
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    content = models.TextField()
    ip_address = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    quoted_post = models.ForeignKey('self', related_name='quotedreply', blank=True, null=True)
    rating = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    reply_order = models.IntegerField(default=1)
```

Now, currently there just over 1600 users, 6000 Posts, and 330,000 PostReply objects in the db for this setup. When I run this SQL query:

```
 SELECT * FROM `forum_post` LIMIT 10000
```

I see that `Query took 0.0241 sec` which is fine. When I browse to the Django admin section of my site, pulling up an individual Post is rapid, as is the paginated list of Posts.

However, if I try and pull up an individual PostReply, it takes around 2-3 **minutes** to load.

Obviously each PostReply admin page will have a dropdown list of all the Posts in it, but can anyone tell me why this or anything else would cause such a dramatically slow query? It's worth noting that the forum itself is pretty fast.

Also, if it *is* something to do with that dropdown list, has anyone got any suggestions for making that more usable?

Comment: Check with `django-debug-toolbar` which query takes such a long time first, it can give you some hints.

Comment: Does it work in the admin?

Comment: It will make the admin slower than usual, but yes, it works.

Comment: First, try django-debug-toolbar. It will tell you which query are time consuming. If the dropdown list is the one slowing the page load, set it as readonly in the admin interface (define it in the admin.py). Only do this if admin shouldn't be able to change the relation between a postreply and a post (which is logical).

Comment: it would also help if you posted your admin class

Comment: There is no admin class for PostReply, just `admin.site.register(PostReply)`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try to add all foreign keys in `raw_id_fields` in admin

```
class PostReplyAdmin(ModelAdmin):
     raw_id_fields = ['user', 'post', 'quoted_post']
```

This will decrease page's load time in change view. The problem is that django loads ForeignModel.objects.all() for each foreign key's dropdowns.

Answer (score 12):

Another way is to add foreign keys in `autocomplete_fields` ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.autocomplete_fields)) in admin

```
class PostReplyAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    autocomplete_fields = ['user', 'post', 'quoted_post']
```

As pointed by @Andrey Nelubin the problem for me was indeed in the page loading all related models for each foreign key's dropdown. However, with `autocomplete_fields` selects are turned into autocomplete inputs (see  figure below), which load options asynchronously.

[image]